# Memory allocation in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am confused about the memory allocation in C++ in terms of the memory areas such as Const data area, Stack, Heap, Freestore, Heap and Global/Static area. I would like to understand the memory allocation pattern in the following snippet. Can anyone help me to understand this.
If there any thing more apart from the variable types mentioned in the example to help understand the concept better please alter the example.

```
class FooBar
{
      int n; //Stored in stack?

      public:

          int pubVar; //stored in stack?

          void foo(int param)  //param stored in stack
          {
                int *pp = new int; //int is allocated on heap.
                n = param;
                static int nStat;  //Stored in static area of memory
                int nLoc;          //stored in stack?
                string str = "mystring"; //stored in stack?
                ..
                if(CONDITION)
                {
                    static int nSIf; //stored in static area of memory
                    int loopvar;     //stored in stack
                    ..
                }
          }
}

int main(int)
{
     Foobar bar;    //bar stored in stack? or a part of it?

     Foobar *pBar;  //pBar is stored in stack

     pBar = new Foobar();  //the object is created in heap?  What part of the object is stored on heap

}
```

EDIT:
What confuses me is, if `pBar = new Foobar();` stores the object on the heap, how come `int nLoc;` and `int pubVar;`, that are components of the object stored on stack? Sounds contradictory to me. Shouldn't the lifetime of `pubvar` and `pBar` be the same?

Comment: The best idea is stop thinking about heap and stack. They don't really exist in C++ (its a Java/C# construct).Think about lifespan (duration) of an object.

Comment: Waitaminute. The stack is a Java construct?! Definitely not. It's a C construct, if not older. But `setjmp/longjmp` made it very clear that C has a stack. Java on the other hand allows objects to escape function scope, which is why the stack concept there doesn't exists (wrt memory; exceptions are another matter)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Heap" and "stack" are outmoded, inaccurate and confusing terms relating to storage duration.

Objects with "automatic storage duration" are what silly people call "stack objects". They're the ones that you will define inside a function as "local variables". They go out of scope when their enclosing block ends.

Objects with "dynamic storage duration" are those that you create on the *free store* with the aid of the keyword `new` (or, if you're silly, `malloc`), and then destroy whenever you like with the keyword `delete` (or, if you're silly, `free`).

There are also objects with "static storage duration" that are subject to all sorts of bizarre rules of initialisation order and things. We tend not to use them in idiomatic C++ as much as we can help it.

As for the specific variables in your code example, your comments are all accurate, despite the failure in terminology.

**Addendum:**

The terms "heap" and "stack" are outdated, relating to back when the most popular runtime libraries used these data structures to store objects which were dynamically- and automatically-allocated, respectively (statically-allocated objects fit into neither category, incidentally).

These days that is not always true, and it's certainly not mandated by the C++ standard, which does not care where things are stored. It only cares about how they are created and destroyed, and about how long they live.

Comment: Actually, note that class members with automatic duration may not be on the physical "stack" (if such a thing even exists), if the encapsulating class was allocated on the "heap" (if such a thing even exists). Another good example of why you should not use these terms.

Comment: I think n and pubVar are stored in the heap, as part of the container object.

Comment: @Ariel: If the implementation uses a heap, then yes in this case the members will happen to be on that "heap" because the object is. C++ has no knowledge of that, though.

Comment: @Ariel: (Certainly, they will be on the _free store_ with it, but they still have automatic storage duration w.r.t. the encapsulating class!)

Comment: BTW - Tomalak, while your comments are mostly accurate, it's non good to treat people as stupid or anything like that. Sounds like you are in the pedestal of wise people while we, mundane arcanes prototypes of intelligent life, are contemplating your majesty. Please, save those words from those who deserve it, which are not those who mistakenly call "stack objects" those that are stored in the stack precisely ☺

Comment: @Ariel: You are correct. I do apologise, and had just minutes before your post changed the word "stupid" to "silly". It's been a long day.

Comment: @Tomalak What confuses me is if  `pBar = new Foobar();` stores the object on the heap, how come `int nLoc;` and `int pubVar;`, that are components of the object stored on stack? Sounds contradictory to me.

Comment: @Mahatma: They are not. This is exactly why the terms "stack" and "heap" are misleading. Please see my example posted as a comment on one of the other answers, a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Tomalak One more clarification, since pp and str are automatic-storage-objects, if I do `pBar = new Foobar();`, the pointer `pp` (not just the int it points to) is allocated on heap. Similarly, `str` and the literal "mystring" is points to are stored on heap. Am I correct?

Comment: @Mahatma: Aside from the fact that you've evidently completely ignored everything I said about the term "heap", actually no. The pointer `pp` is not a member of the class `Foobar`; it's just a local variable of a function. Despite appearances, member functions aren't really "inside" a class; certainly not in terms of storage. The "fall-through" of "heap-ness" only applies to actual member variables.

Comment: AFAIK, the term "heap", referring to "where variables with dynamic storage duration are place", was never meant to imply a heap data structure, although the term "stack" was meant to imply a stack - specifically, the one implicitly created by using special processor opcodes that manipulate a 'stack pointer' register. Also, "the heap" is normally considered to include static storage space.

Comment: then where is the int that is pointed to by pp and the string literal allocated? Is it not in free-store?

Comment: Is it that upsetting that people use "stack" and "heap"? Over time, words can take on meaning beyond what they literally represent. People associate them as such, and it's very condescending to just label them as misguided. Countless words in the English language have adopted meanings entirely removed from their origins.

Comment: ITs not that heap/stack are outdated they are just not correct for C++. It is something that Java developers brought over from their understanding of the world when they try and learn C++. I also find the description not quite correct. The member 'n' is an automatic variable, but this does not mean it is a stack variable this is dependent on where it's parent is allocated ((if stack/heap exist) bar and pbar are allocated in different areas thus their members would be in different areas (yet they (the members) are always automatic)

Comment: Also. The stack does not really exist anymore. Each stack frame can just as easily be implemented as an object on the heap (where heap is just all memory not used by the OS). I read a paper that MS was doing this to prevent stack smashing having predictable results (not sure if they still do it).

Comment: @Martin York: I think you're refering to non-contiguous stacks and ASLR respectively. They're distinct techniques, but both don't alter the CS concept of a stack (a LIFO datastructure)

Comment: @MSalters: Absolutely. LIFO is the key. Its just that most undergrads simplify this as a contiguous area of memory growing down memory that is distinct from the heap (An easy way to teach the concept but oversimplified).

Comment: @Martin "contiguous area of memory growing down " was how I thought. Some answers I got here also reflects the same thought. Alarming to hear it's all wrong. Where can I find the CORRECT explanation.

Comment: @Mahatma: It's implementation and platform-specific, not related to the C++ language. :)

Comment: @Mahatma: As a programmer it does not matter to you how it actually works. If you must think of a stack then think of it growing down in contiguous memory (its an easy simile). But better to forget the concept of a stack completely. It is not relevant to C++. Starting point for research: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: @Toolbox: The fact that this question even exists goes a long way to show that the terms are ambiguous and confusing. It's not just that they've "changed meaning" at all.

Answer (score 5):

I've updated your annotations with what I believe is more correct.  Note that Tomalak is correct that 'stack' and 'heap' are not specified by the standard, and mechanisms other than a stack might be used to pass parameters to store automatic variables.

However, I still use those terms because they are actually used quite often in compiler implementations, the terms are more or less well-understood (or easy to understand), and I think they still pragmatically illustrate what you're interested in knowing.

```
class Foobar
{
      int n; //Stored wherever the current object is stored
             //  (might be static memory, stack or heap depending 
             //  on how the object is allocated)

      public:

          int pubVar; //Stored wherever the current object is stored 
                      //  (might be static memory, stack or heap depending 
                      //  on how the object is allocated)

          void foo(int param)  //param stored in stack or register
          {
                int *pp = new int; //int is allocated on heap.
                n = param;
                static int nStat;  //Stored in static area of memory
                int nLoc;          //stored in stack or register
                string str = "mystring"; // `str` is stored in stack, however 
                                         //    the string object may also use heap 
                                         //    to manage its data
                ..
                if(CONDITION)
                {
                    static int nSIf; //stored in static area of memory
                    int loopvar;     //stored in stack or register
                    ..
                }
          }
}

int main(int)
{
     Foobar bar;    //bar stored in stack

     Foobar *pBar;  //pBar is stored in stack

     pBar = new Foobar();  //the object is created in heap.  
                           //   The non-static data members are stored in that
                           //   memory block.

}
```

Comment: They're ambiguous and confusing, unfortunately. It may well be the case that "most people" use them in this way, but that's hardly an argument to avoid the ambiguity. "Most people" think that Sydney is the capital of Australia; that does not in any way make it right.

Comment: @Micheal "depending on how the object is allocated" is not clear to me. Do you mean the following distinction: Foobar bar; (//here object is allocated on stack) Foobar *pBar = new Foobar(); (//here object is allocated on heap)

Comment: @Mahatma: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: While it's virtually impossible for memory allocated using the free store mechanism (i.e. `new`) to be on the stack, I'm not at all convinced that automatic variables will **have** to be found on the stack or in a register. I guess the implementation is free to put the on the heap just the same. **Why** would it want to do such thing is a whole new question, though...

Comment: @conio automatic-storage-duration objects that are members of a dynamically-allocated object will of course be stored with that dynamically-allocated object, which means the free store... or the "heap" as you put it.

Comment: Missed that pp itself is stack/register (though the memory it points to is heap).

Comment: @Tomalak: My point is that even if they **aren't** members of dynamically-allocated objects, the implementation is still free to put them **wherever** it wants. Implementation are absolutely free to allocate them using the operating systems dynamic allocating mechanisms. As long as it exists for the duration of the enclosing scope. That's virtually all the standard requires.

Comment: @conio: Absolutely! I'm well aware of that fact, which is the same thing I've been saying throughout various threads on this question. The implementation can dynamically-allocate an array on an abacus if it pleases.

Comment: @conio: Ah, my message directed at you 2 days ago was intended for Mahatma, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tomalak,

> C++ does not care where things are
>   stored. It only cares about how they
>   are constructed and destroyed, and
>   about how long they live.

How it happens, is implementation defined, the compiler might optimize in such a way, that you won't have anything stored on the "stack" when you expect it. The way allocation on the heap happens is defined by the implementation of new/malloc or some third party function (new might call malloc).

What most likely will happen in your example, is this:

```
Foobar bar; // bar will *most likely* be allocated on the "stack".
Foobar *pBar; // pBar will *most likely* be allocated on the "stack".
pBar = new Foobar(); // pBar will stay as is, and point to the location on the "heap" where your memory is allocated by new.
```

A few things that you might be wondering about. A C-style array, like `int array[5]` is not stored the same way as a `int* pointer= new int[5]`, the second case will most likely use more memory, since it stores not only the memory for the array, but also memory on the "stack" for the pointer.

Static constants such as `5` and `"cake"` are usually stored in a separate .DATA section of the executable.

The important thing to understand when using C++, most of these things are implementation defined.

Comment: Since you say *most likely*, can the allocation of /* Foobar bar; */ happen in the heap?

Comment: @Mahatma: Absolutely. Depends where you write it! BTW on SO backticks can delimit code samples and format them for you.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate "Depends where you write it". I mean an example where `Foobar bar;` gets allocated on heap.

Comment: @Mahatma: `struct Foobar {}; struct Foo { Foobar bar; }; int main() { Foo* x = new Foo(); delete x; }` -- the only `Foobar` in this program is in the free store, or "heap" as you put it.... even though within the context of `Foo`, it has automatic storage duration (which is why your instinct tells you, incorrectly, that it is on the imaginary "stack").

Comment: Is it the same, in terms of allocation if I replace `struct` with `class`?

Comment: Aren't there embedded systems that don't even *have* a stack? Or was it that they don't have a heap?

Comment: @Michael I think it's that they don't use a heap.

Answer (score 0):

Non-static data members are "inside" each instance of that class: whether that is on the stack or heap – or elsewhere – is unknown by just looking at the member in the class definition.  It does not make sense to talk about the storage of non-static data members without talking about storage of the instance of the class to which they belong.

```
struct A {
  int n;  // you cannot say n is always on the stack, or always on the heap, etc.
};

int main() {
  A a;  // a is on the stack, so a.n is also on the stack
  A *p = new A();  // *p, which means the object pointed to by p, is on the heap,
                   // so p->n is also on the heap
                   // p itself is on the stack, just like a
  return 0;
}

A global;  // global is neither on the stack nor on the heap, so neither is global.n
```

"The stack" is where variables scoped to the lifetime of a single function invocation go; this is also called "automatic storage duration".  There are various stack allocation strategies and, notably, each thread has its own stack – though which is "the" stack should be clear from context.  There's interesting things happening with split stacks (which allow growing and shrinking), but in that case, it's still one stack split into multiple pieces.

"The heap" is only a misnomer in that "the" refers to the "main" heap, as used by malloc and various forms of new; this is also called "dynamic storage duration".

Global variables, static data members, and function-level statics belong to neither the stack nor heap; also called "static storage duration".