# How do games like GTA IV not fragment the heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm interested in the type of memory management a game like GTA IV might use given that it needs to create and delete lots of objects very quickly. How do the avoid fragmenting the heap and other things. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687310/memory-allocation-patterns-in-c/4687324#4687324

Comment: Grab a copy of Modern C++ Design.  You'll be taken through the steps to build a fast allocator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They use things like [memory pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool), specialized allocators, and specialized container classes.

1. The [Hoard Memory](http://www.hoard.org/) allocator for multi-threaded programs.
2. EA's version of the [STL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html).  Contains allocators, containers,

Comment: memory pooling! yes, forgot that term :)

Answer (score 8):

While this paper does not specifically refer to games, it provides a good roundup of the kind of custom memory allocators that people often employ in C and C++ applications in an attempt to improve performance (and is a bit of a cautionary tale).

**[Reconsidering custom memory allocation](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/berger-oopsla2002.pdf)**, Berger, Zorn & McKinley, OOPSLA 2002

*Programmers hoping to achieve performance improvements often use custom memory allocators. This in-depth study examines eight applications that use custom allocators. Surprisingly, for six of these applications, a state-of-the-art general-purpose allocator (the Lea allocator) performs as well as or better than the custom allocators. The two exceptions use regions, which deliver higher performance (improvements of up to 44%). Regions also reduce programmer burden and eliminate a source of memory leaks. However, we show that the inability of programmers to free individual objects within regions can lead to a substantial increase in memory consumption. Worse, this limitation precludes the use of regions for common programming idioms, reducing their usefulness. We present a generalization of general-purpose and region-based allocators that we call reaps. Reaps are a combination of regions and heaps, providing a full range of region semantics with the addition of individual object deletion. We show that our implementation of reaps provides high performance, outperforming other allocators with region-like semantics. We then use a case study to demonstrate the space advantages and software engineering benefits of reaps in practice. Our results indicate that programmers needing fast regions should use reaps, and that most programmers considering custom allocators should instead use the Lea allocator.*

Comment: Amusing that the first answer would link to your blog :)

Answer (score 7):

There are two very good `malloc` implementations for multi-threaded implementations:

- `tcmalloc`: by Google
- `jemalloc`: used by Apache (for example)

Here is Facebook's article about [improving jemalloc](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/scalable-memory-allocation-using-jemalloc/480222803919). It's about 5 times faster that Hoard's memory allocator in the current top answer :)

Comment: That result is quite anomalous - I am hoping to work with Jason Evans to see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @EmeryBerger: it surprised me too, I certainly hope you find it out, good memory allocators are the first brick to build fast software :)

Answer (score 6):

Creating and destroying lots of objects really quickly doesn't necessarily mean heap fragmentation. Often, if the objects are of the same size, then the space freed by one can be allocated for the next.

Often, even just as an optimization, a program might not free and delete memory for objects, but keep old ones in a pool and simply grab one and overwrite the contents to create a 'new' object.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence. So many people talk about fragmentation and have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 2):

I think because their objects are mostly of the same size they can use some internal memory manager which doesn't actually free memory, but marks it as available and next time chunk of ~size is allocated it returns it.

Comment: That's what simple implementations of `free()` do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of games use some of the memory allocators mentioned here.  dlmalloc is one that we have used with great success (we have tied it into Lua).  You can get information on dlmalloc [here](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/index.html).

One other thing that I would mention though, is that not all games have to use dynamic memory allocation.  We have employed mempools and use of static memory regions for most of our gameplay data.  Only the systems that require dynamic allocation do so (Lua and some third party libraries).  Everything else that we do comes out of static buffers.  We use no STL in gamecode either, which helps limit the "damage" of memory fragmentation.

Comment: Note that any real OS (i.e. an desktop/server/workstation OS except Windows) uses an allocator that's algorithmically very close to `dlmalloc`, with various *improvements*, already. The only systems where dropping in `dlmalloc` as a `malloc` replacement might serve any purpose are Windows and perhaps game consoles (no idea what their libraries look like).

Comment: That's not quite right. Linux-based systems do generally use the glibc allocator, which is indeed based on dlmalloc. However, Windows, FreeBSD, Solaris, AIX, and Mac OS X all use different memory allocators, none of which are based on dlmalloc.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that I was talking about non-real OSes.  Personal bias aside, my answer was indeed coming from the windows and console point of view.