# Is there memory area called 'stack' in C++ to store automatic variables

Tags: c++, memory-management

Is there a specific area in memory called stack in C++ where automatic variables are getting stored.

Comment: Yes... that's exactly what it means for a C++ variable to have automatic storage class.

Comment: This is one of those questions where academia fails to explain themselves properly.  Back in college, professors often referred to the "stack" and the "heap" (when they really meant local or free store).  This is largely due to how it was on older systems that actually implemented the standard in this manner (professors often didn't mention that part).

Comment: @Zac: I was never sure whether the professors were irresponsibly abstracting those critical details away, or whether they have been in academia too long to actually know that they have changed!

Comment: @Martin that's not true at all. The spec says "The storage duration of member subobjects, base class subobjects and array elements is that of their complete object", and that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Well spotted.

Comment: @Zac: how exactly have things changed? The stack is still a stack, and the free store is as much a heap today as it was 20 years ago. I don't see how this has anything to do with academia, or with the implementation changing. It's just that the C++ standard doesn't mandate any specific kind of memory layout, such as a stack.

Comment: @jalf:  The stack was a common implementation of the automatic storage requirement of the C++ standard ~5 years ago.  These says it is an implementation, but there are others as well.  Professors tend to refer to the stack as the ONLY implementation of automatic storage (if they even tell you it is automatic storage at all), which can be misleading.

Comment: @Zac: which other implementations are used (for C++)? Btw, in my experience, academia usually gets this right, as professors tend to be more interested in the theoretical properties than the particular implementation details. I think it's the "real" world that tends to get hung up on the "stack" and "heap" thing.

Answer (score 17):

No. The standard only mentions:

> — static storage duration
>
> — automatic storage duration
>
> — dynamic storage duration

There is no such thing as 'stack memory' in C++. Yet it's common to say that the automatic storage duration variables are 'allocated on the stack' since it's the way it's implemented from computer science point of view. 'The heap' is another term that usually refers to dynamic storage duration but is not mentioned in the standard.

Comment: In other words: "the stack" is an implementation detail, common to many implementations but not mandated by the standard.

Comment: Interestingly, "free store" IS mentioned in the standard, but only in the index.

Comment: @Jonatahan: not quite. GMan refers to the computer science POV. In that POW, automatic variables form a stack; the standard requires it. But the standard does not require using the "machine stack" to implement that abstract stack.

Comment: There is no such thing as "stack memory" in the C++ standard. That does not mean that there is no such thing as stack memory in a real C++ implementation.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: Is it even an implementation detail or a figment of the collective imagination. I define a stack as a contiguous block of memory that grows down from the top of memory towards the heap (that's how it was visualized for me in education). Does that memory structure even exist. The best you can say about the actual data structure is that it is a FIFO queue. I would argue that the stack (as you were tought in University) does not actually exist. It is a  bunch of linked frames scattered through memory just like any other dynamically allocated object.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: The only reason 'Free Store' is mentioned is to make sure that the memory allocated by new **can** be considered distinct from the memory allocated by malloc.

Comment: @Martin Ah, but that's an implementation detail of the operating system and the underlying hardware, and quite far removed from the C++ standard. ;p

Comment: @Jay: the question is about C++ here, not C++ implementations. C++ implementations may not have a memory called 'stack' either. Some may allocate the 'stack' on the heap, etc... @Martin: "I disagree" there's nothing to agree here. I say that it's the misconception that I hear many times among other programmers. "A member of a class has automatic storage duration" agree. "FIFO queue"? AFAIK it's a LIFO, which is also called a 'stack' in computer science. It doesn't have to be contiguous, although it usually is, to prevent dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: @ybungalobill you agreed to a wrong statement. See my comment to the question. The whole point of storage duration is that it applies to storage an object uses. It's obvious that a (member-) subobject must be assigned the same storage duration as its complete object.

Comment: ok ok... @Martin disagree @Johannes agree :) "Block-scope variables explicitly declared register or not explicitly declared static or extern have automatic
storage duration."

Comment: @ybungalobill: Well, not to get into an argument, but doesn't the very phrase "C++ implementation" indicate that this has to do with C++? It is certainly valid and valuable to distinguish between the standard and any given implementation. But I don't agree that a question about "how does C++ work" is not validly answered with reference to actual implementations.

Answer (score 3):

- Most processors have a memory area called the stack.
- C++ compilers typically use the processor stack for automatic variables but are not required to do so. One very common case is when a variable is kept in a processor register and never stored to memory.

Comment: In that case how is the LIFO ordering ensured for storing variables during nested method calls?

Comment: @iJeeves: it's used as an optimization when no nested calls are done, or when they are inlined, or when the parameters are passed through the registers and not used after the call.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to have generated a debate about whether the correct answer is what is defined by the standard, or what is actually done in most if not all implementations. Rather than continuing to snipe with comments, let me give a long answer.

A simple analogy: Suppose that you were trying to teach someone beginning geography. At one point the student asks, "Is France in Europe?" What would you consider the correct answer to such a question?

(a) No. The French Constitution does not specify the borders of the country. Therefore, it is impossible to say where France is.

(b) No. It is possible that someday in the future the Earth will be destroyed and French refugees will settle on another planet and reconstitute their nation there. Or there may be alternative universes in which France is located in a different place. Therefore, we cannot say where France is.

(c) Yes. France is in Europe.

(d) Basically yes. The central government and the bulk of the population of France is in Europe, though they do control territories elsewhere, like French Guiana in South America and Reunion Island in the Indian Ocean.

I would give answer (c) if the question was being asked in a general way or by a beginning student, or (d) if the context indicated that a more precise answer was called for. Apparently some of the posters here insist that the correct answer is (a) or (b). They say that it is literally WRONG to look at the world as it actually is, and that the only correct answer to a question is to look for some document that describes the world as some authority declares it ought to be.

If you think this analogy is strained and you want a more purely IT discussion, let me offer a closer analogy. Suppose you are teaching a class on web design and a student asks, "How can I express complex mathematical formulas in a web page?"

Would you say that the correct answer is, "Use the <MATH> tag, and it's associated tags like ABOVE and BELOW and ROOT and ARRAY, as defined in the HTML 3.2 standard."

Such an answer would be absolutely true in the sense that the HTML 3.2 standard does include such tags. Unfortunately, no major browser implements these tags. The fact that it is in a standard is not of much practical use.

I could say the same about many features of IT products. "How do I limit the number of rows of output from a SQL query?" The real answer depends on which database engine you are using. Off the top of my head I don't know what the SQL standard says, if it provides any means at all, and I don't care, because it doesn't matter. In real life I do not run the ANSI SQL standard on my database server, I run Postgres or Oracle or MySQL or some other actual product.

I'm not saying that standards don't matter in general. OF COURSE we should have good standards, and products should comply with them to the maximum extent possible. But in the real world, what ultimately matters is implementation.

To insist that it doesn't matter how the computer ACTUALLY works in real life, but that we can ONLY consider how someone said he thought it should work, is not useful to someone trying to write programs that run on real computers.

(Yes, there is a practical case to be made for writing programs that will work with any standards-compliant compiler, if you're interested in cross-platform compatibility and upwards compatibility. We could certainly debate the wisdom of using tricks that depend on a specific implementation: when is performance or coding convenience outweighed by the fragility of a non-standard implementation?)

Frankly, I think this sort of answer is a pedantry that just confuses the beginning student. When the beginning student asks what continent France is on, he doesn't want or need a long string of hypotheticals, theoreticals, and special cases. He needs a simple and direct answer. Same thing with when he asks, "Are my function variables stored on a stack?" or "Is my program loaded into RAM at run time?"

Answer (score 1):

Vague question, but yes.  A program's stack in C++ typically starts high in the virtual address space of the program and moves 'down' towards the virtual address space of the program heap.

EDIT:

Because I have started a controversy in saying yes to this, I will append to the answer.  The C++ standard does not call specifically for a stack to be used to implement local storage.  It is, however, a common implementation practice to do so as described above.

Comment: Where does the standard mention virtual address space? :) The 'stack' is a common implementation detail, but C++ *the language* has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Well, there's the standard, and then there is what actually happens.  It may not be technically correct to say the C++ standard specifies a stack, but I am willing to bet when he codes C++ it will be using a program stack. :)

Comment: @James: -1. The program's stack has nothing to do with C++. To say "a program's stack in C++" does anything is wildly incorrect.

Comment: @James: And you only know what actually happens *because* of the standard. :/

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: But the popular implementations of C++ on, e.g., x86 are going to have a stack and that's where those variables will live.  It's not wrong to mention that, as long as you are aware that whether or not there is a stack is irrelevant to understanding variable lifetime or program behavior (i.e., that it's an implementation detail).

Comment: @siride: Sure, but James did not clarify that, so the OP would not be aware.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: fair enough

Comment: @Tomalak et al: The original question did not say, "What is required by the C++ standard?" It asked what happens in a C++ program. In practice, function variables are stored on a stack. While I have nothing against clarifying what is in the standard versus what is in a practical implementation, I think it's a little pedantic to say that a "real world" answer is wrong. If someone said, "Can I write to my hard drive from a C++ program?", surely the answer is "Yes". The fact that the standard does not specifically refer to hard drives is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jay: "In practice, function variables are stored on a stack." Except when they're not, like when they're stored in registers or optimized away completely.

Comment: In 32 bit windows the stack is often lower than the program, and the heap is above.  Stack around 0x100000 (used from the end towards this value), Program around 0x400000, heap somewhere above, 3rd party and CRT dlls around 0x10000000 and above.  Windows core dlls around 0x7C000000 and above.  None of this is fixed, and should never be depended upon, its just common places to find these things and very easy to check with debugging features in VS or ollydbg or another debugger.

Comment: @Jay: "In practice, function variables are stored on a stack." Simply incorrect, or at the very least a gross generalisation. You could stand to learn something from this answer and this comment thread.

Comment: @Jay: FWIW, I would of course answer "yes" to that hypothetical question. However, I would _not_ answer "yes" to "do C++ programs run from my hard drive?", even though in practice this is probably the case a lot of the time.

Comment: @Jimbo: in 32 bit windows you may have many stacks, one per each thread, that are scattered around you address space. Also the load address of the image can be specified and even randomized. That's used as part of some techniques to decrease vulnerability.

Comment: @Steve & Tomalek: Okay, I'll agree, a more complete answer would be that function variables are USUALLY stored in a stack, though some may be stored in registers, and there may be some other special cases. Yes, one could imagine an implementation in which they are stored in some totally different way. Do you know of any such implementation? I don't, though I freely admit that I have not studied any large number of implementations.

Comment: @Tomalek: When you say that my answer is "incorrect", I take it that you mean something like "Correct in every case or almost every case in the real world, but one could imagine a hypothetical future technology or alternative universe in which it would not be correct." I think you have a great future in politics.

Comment: @Tomalak: RE "do my C++ programs run from the hard drive": That's an ambiguous question. But why would you say no? Could it be because by any interpretation of the question, the answer is somewhere between "never" and "usually, but there are many exceptions"? But then you are saying no because in actual implementations, the answer is often no. So I'm not sure what your point is here.

Comment: @Jay: I am acknowledging the very real possibility that these implementations exist. I do not understand your apparent desire to actively restrict your view to the few that you know. I can't see the benefit.

Answer (score -4):

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687310/memory-allocation-in-c/4687324#4687324), where I explain this in detail.

In summary, quoted from it:

> The terms "heap" and "stack" are
>   outdated, relating to back when the
>   most popular runtime libraries used
>   these data structures to store objects
>   which were dynamically- and
>   automatically-allocated, respectively
>   (statically-allocated objects fit into
>   neither category, incidentally).
>
> These days that is not always true,
>   and it's certainly not mandated by the
>   C++ standard, which does not care
>   where things are stored. It only cares
>   about how they are created and
>   destroyed, and about how long they
>   live.

Hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: Feel free to post a new question if you wish to ask about the memory area called "stack" that might be found on the most popular OSs and language implementation runtimes. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: what do you call these entities then? I still call them stack and heap and since there is usually enough context to not confuse them with the data structures I will continue to do so, barring good alternatives. Apart from that, the call stack *is* a stack.

Comment: @Konrad: I use the term _free store_ where you say "heap", and there is no need to talk about the place where automatic- or static- storage duration objects live. Unfortunately, even though you will not get confused, helping to propogate the use of the terms leads to language newcomers getting confused. :)

Comment: @ Konrad Rudolph: Do you really. If you think back do you actually mention either stack or heap in any conversation? I find myself just saying `dynamically allocated` (newed) or `local`. The fact that that its in a heap (`Free Store`) or local (when `bound to the local scope`) does not really come up that much in conversation (or documents). The question does it actually come up? or are you thinking that's how I was tough all those years ago?

Comment: @Tomalak: “there is no need to talk about …” – I beg to differ. Of course there is, otherwise we wouldn’t. The call stack is an important concept in computer science.

Comment: @Martin: I’m currently writing my thesis about a parallelization framework. Thread-local storage and a thread’s call stack appear in every second sentence (this is an exaggeration). And as soon as you talk about implementing a compiler mentions of the call stack will be ubiquitous (unless you’re working on a very esoteric compiler). It’s true that I rarely use terms like “stack allocated” to refer to local variables though.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: OK. That I can see.

Comment: @Konrad: I'll concede the stack is slightly different. There's never a need to use the incorrect term "heap" here, though. I find it amusing that so many people are downvoting answers like this, because they are so set in their incorrect and misleading ways.

Comment: @Tomalak It is very wrong to propagate that there is no call stack. Where else you think the automatic variables get stored if I am using any REAL compiler on a REAL machine?

Comment: @iJeeves: "REAL" is not defined by the language. Also consider registers and items that are completely optimised out. You are trying to simplify matters to "real-life scenarios", but [presumably accidentally] missing out large chunks of those very "real-life scenarios". For this to be commonplace -- which it is -- is very dangerous for language newcomers, who take it as gospel.

Comment: @Tomalak: By "REAL" he has clearly indicated what is actually done in an implementation. To say that the standard does not define implementation details beyond what is necessary to meet the standard is pretty much a tautology. You seem to insist that when I say "C++", I must use that term only to refer to the standard and not to an implementation. I'm not sure who passed that law. Surely it is reasonable to say, for example, "My C++ compiler requires 80 MB to install." Yes, there are times when it is important to distinguish the standard from any given implementation.

Comment: @Jay: What is "REAL" for you may not be "REAL" for someone else. Further, "REAL" for you may not be "REAL" even for you in four years time. The C++ standard is [largely] fixed; that is the reason for its existence. Sticking to what it defines is a safe and sane rule of thumb. Anything further is just gambling.

Comment: -5 for this; +18 for another answer saying the same thing. Excellent.