# sizeof() std::vector (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, sizeof

There is a topic already on this topic but I have doubts still. To calculate the size of a vector, which one is correct:

```
sizeof(VEC) + sizeof(int) * VEC.capacity()
```

or

```
VEC.capacity() * (sizeof(VEC) + sizeof(int))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof() a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373189/sizeof-a-vector)

Comment: @jrok: That's only a guess, depending on how the implementation works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What do you mean by size of the vector? The size of the vector object is just

```
sizeof(vec);
```

If you are interested in how much memory the vector has allocated on the heap, you can use

```
vec.capacity()*sizeof(T)
```

So, if you add these, you'll get how much memory you've "lost" because of the vector.

```
vec.capacity()*sizeof(T) + sizeof(vec)
```

Please note that exactly how much memory is allocated is implementation-dependent. It's just that the formula above will be *practically* correct (or approximately correct) on most if not all implementations.

Comment: That's only a guess, depending on how the implementation works.

Comment: I think that, given the constraints on how a `vector` *can* be validly implemented, this gives a correct *lower bound* on the amount of memory a `vector` and its contents occupy. +1.

Comment: But it seems that allocated memory for a dynamic array and a vector would be the same if their number of members and types are the same.

Comment: @Armen: heap itself is an implementation detail (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693885/is-there-memory-area-called-stack-in-c-to-store-automatic-variables)

Comment: @Shibli: A dynamic array has no members, unlike the vector template

Comment: @Vlad: I know that, thank you. But it's a common term easily understandable by people. Easier than "dynamic allocation"

Comment: I believe free store is the language lawyer's term for heap.

Comment: @Armen: Well, theoretically vector _can_ use some statically preallocated memory for storing the data. It could even share the data between different different vector instances (using a kind of copy-on-write strategy).

Comment: With respect to the _practically_ correct: the "best" approach to implementing `std::vector<T>` is to have the actually object store a pointer to `T` which is a pointer to the start of the elements and have the controlling data (the `std::vector<T>`'s size, capacity, and allocator) immediately precede the values. This approach isn't necessarily portable but it hasn't to be since `std::vector<T>` is part of the implementation. In addition to the control data of the `std::vector<T>` the memory manage system typically also adds a couple of bytes in front of the allocate memory.

Comment: sorry if i am asking an obvious question, but what you exactly mean by "memory the vector has allocated on the heap" vs "how much memory you've "lost"". Also, will this work for `std::vector<bool>` as I have heard that they are implemented differently.

Comment: @FredFoo it's not even a lower bound, because of the as-if rule. If the data members of a particular vector object only live in registers, are they occupying memory?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know the size of the data contained within the vector

```
std::vector<int> vec;
...
vec.size() * sizeof(decltype(vec)::value_type))
```

If the type is changed from int to say long long nothing else has to be changed. I find this solution safer then the one using the type in the sizeof because it one can easily be changed without the other.

```
std::vector<long long> vec; // lets go from int to int64
...
vec.size() * sizeof(int); // woops problem on the horizon
```

Comment: This is surprising that there is no existing method to get directly vec.size() * sizeof(decltype(vec)::value_type) given that it's quite long.