# Byte size used by std::vector

Tags: c++

I'm interfacing `std::vector` to a C program which needs to know the size in bytes.

Can I do this without the expression `sizeof(vec[0])`?

```
void *dest = get_dest();
std::vector<T> vec;
memcpy(dest, vec.data(), vec.size() * sizeof(vec[0]));
```

Please do not offer C++ style alternatives to `memcpy`.

Comment: You could do `sizeof(T)` I guess?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778091/sizeof-stdvector-c

Comment: What's wrong with `sizeof(vec[0])`?

Comment: Indeed. `sizeof(vec[0])` has the advantage of automatically remaining correct even if `T` changes, while `sizeof(T)` must be manually kept in sync if `T` ever changes (and hence is a potential source of errors).

Comment: @tetra No, the answers to that question do not answer this one.  Please read more than the title when closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @Praetorian I know that `sizeof(vec[0])` is evaluated at compile time and will not raise an exception even if `vec[0]` would at runtime. But it "feels" like (possibly) dereferencing a null pointer. Just asking out of curiosity and trying to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T, class A>
std::size_t bytes_in_vector( std::vector<T,A>const& v ){
  return v.size()*sizeof(T);
}
template<class A>
std::size_t bytes_in_vector( std::vector<bool,A> const& )=delete;
```

however, there is little wrong with `sizeof(vec[0])` so long as `T` is not `bool`.  If `T` is `bool` you are not allowed to use `memcpy`.

Comment: Very cool! I didn't know you could extract the template arguments like this.