# Selecting between two constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

Problem: I have a non-copyable object with two  constructors. I need to create an object with one of the constructors and then use it within some common code:-

With a copyable object it would look like this, and be easy:

```
Object a;

if (condition) 
   a = Object(p1);
else
   a = Object(p2,p3,p4);

a.doSomething();
```

But, the object is non-copyable, so I've had to do this:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<Object> a;

if (condition) 
   a = new Object(p1);
else
   a = new Object(p2,p3,p4);

a->doSomething();
```

This feels too complex. Is there a better solutiuon?

Comment: You are not *copying*, you are *assigning*, so strictly there is no problem if the class in non-copyable, as long as it is *assignable*.

Comment: .. though usually both go hand in hand. Certainly, you'd hope so.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm having a hard time thinking of a justification for providing an assignment operator but no copy constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I've always rather wished providing both or neither were language-mandated.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It was just a call for more precise wording. I am pretty sure the thing isn't assignable either.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's frequent to provide a (usually private) copy constructor to support cloning, but to not support assignment.

Comment: @JamesKanze: `private` being the key -- that would be a fair exemption

Comment: the answer is no.  there is no better solution.  now watch a zillion answers show up that do not actually answer the question.

Comment: Is C++11 an option?  And if so, is the object moveable?

Comment: You could try something with `unsigned char raw[sizeof(Object)];`, `Object &a = *reinterpret_cast<Object*>(raw);` and `::new(&a) Object(p1);`, but watch for alignment and destruction.

Comment: Along @BenjaminLindley's suggestion: If `Object` had a useful move assignment operator, the first block of code would compile with no changes.

Comment: I would also add: even if the Object class were copiable/assignable, I would still go for the second solution. Why copy a possibly complex object when you can just construct it (once) and be done with it? Different story if you have move semantics, as Benjamin Lindley pointed out...

Comment: @juanchopanza : My mistake: It's neither assignable or copyable, and C++11 is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very terrible hack, assuming `Object` is default-constructible:

```
Object a;
a.~Object();

if (condition) { ::new (&a) Object(p1); }
else           { ::new (&a) Object(p2, p3, p4); }
```

[Don't use this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8829548/596781)

Another option is using a union, but you'll need to invoke the destructor manually in that setup as well.

---

A cleaner solution could be achieved with [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/) (using [in-place factories](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/in_place_factories.html)). (Thanks to @K-Ballo for digging up the details!)

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>

struct Object
{
    explicit Object(int) {}
    explicit Object(int, float, std::string) {}

    Object(Object const &)             = delete;
    Object(Object &&)                  = delete;
    Object & operator=(Object const &) = delete;
    Object & operator=(Object &&)      = delete;
};

boost::optional<Object> a;

if (condition) { a = boost::in_place(0); }
else           { a = boost::in_place(0, 1.0f, "two" ); }
```

Comment: Optional has some old form of emplacement, with an in place flag or something similar

Comment: @K-ballo: You're right, [in-place factories](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/in_place_factories.html). I was going to look it up but then forgot. I'll update this post if I find out more.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The point of them is to use them with types that are not _copy constructible_... but I've never used them, I will see if I can figure them out

Comment: @KerrekSB: From the examples (well, tests), it seems that the usage would be `boost::optional<Object> v; v = boost::in_place<Object>(p2, p3, p4);`

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's taught me most, even if I'm going to leave the code the same!

Answer (score 3):

Looks perfectly reasonable to me just the way it is. It's clear, simple and relatively concise.

Comment: If only it didn't incur an unneeded allocation

Comment: Actually, the allocation is for the actual object itself.  scoped_ptr sits on the stack.

Comment: @thang: The `scoped_ptr` is an object too, and has _automatic storage duration_, which may or may not entail any "stack". It certainly has an allocation, though

Comment: what I meant is that when you do scoped_ptr<T> a;, the scoped_ptr object is stored on the stack.  if you do scoped_ptr<T> a; and not do scoped_ptr<T> a(new T), no allocation is performed.  if you look above to the "correct" answer, no allocation actually happens because placement new is used on a block of memory on the stack.

Comment: @thang: Allocation on the "stack" is still allocation

Comment: not sure why you call it the "stack" instead of stack.  First, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161053/c-which-is-faster-stack-allocation-or-heap-allocation and then see here http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Quotation-Marks-Correctly

Comment: as you know, even with pooling, a heap allocation can be costly and can cause unnecessary fragmentation.  In that sense when k-ballo and I were saying "allocation" (notice correct use of quotation), we were, by Gricean implicature, implying heap allocation.

Comment: @thang: Ah, the old principle of "saying something different to what you mean". And why do I use quotations about "stack"? Because this question is tagged `c++`, a high-level computer programming language from which some implementation details are abstracted. First, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687310/memory-allocation-in-c and then stop being a smart-arse.

Comment: Actually, it's more of "meaning something that is different from the obviously wrong interpretation".  Unfortunately, it is difficult to discuss efficiency or complexity (as used by OP) without bringing in implementation.  If know an example of a compiler implementation of that specific use of automatic storage duration without using a stack, I would be interested in knowing.  As it turns out, the "unneeded allocation" can in practical scenarios be a bottleneck, which, without implementation considerations, would not be obvious.  In fact, it has more important implications than the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the *complexity*... If you need to construct efficiently based on an if-condition declaring a pointer and using new is your only option. What you don't necessarily need to do is:

1. Use a scoped_ptr (altough that's usually a good idea)
2. Have the constructor in the if in your "main" code. Yours is a typical use case for a factory (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

EDIT: added "efficiently" in the second sentence.

Comment: Good shout about the factory.

Comment: Well, without context the if-else may be enough and the factory an overkill... but good design seldom is! And this may be a good learning opportunity.

Comment: -1 "If you need to construct based on an if-condition declaring a pointer and using new is your only option" is incorrect.

Comment: Right Alf. Added "efficiently" (meaning, construct once only) to make it correct.

Comment: @Epikorus: dynamic allocation is pretty inefficient, in general. so i'm afraid the edit adding the word "efficiently" only made things worse.

Comment: @Alf: the question and the snippet in it don't in any way suggest that efficiency is a concern, so I went for the simplest (C++03) suggestion with the best design and efficiency for what we see. Using 'new', construction happens once only and there's the efficiency. Should efficiency be such a serious problem that dynamic allocation is a concern, well then I think, depending on the **context**, many other things can/should be done: e.g. removing the if at construction (maybe moving the choice at compile-time) or using a different memory allocator (like one with a preallocated pool), etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto const doSomethingTo = []( Object&& o ) { o.doSomething(); };
doSomethingTo( condition? Object( p1 ) : Object( p1, p2, p3 ) );
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler.

---

**EDIT**: the code above, when the `Object( Object&& )` constructor is `private`, fails to compile with MSVC 11.0 (yes even last year's November CTP), but does compile fine with MinGW g++ 4.7.1 and with some version of [clang](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=88b7bff9908a78f85574efcf124d2f01).

It appears that [it should compile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406177/464581).

So, it's probably a bug in Visual C++ – but unfortunately I didn't find an easy workaround.

---

An *uneasy* workaround for the assumed-to-be Visual C++ compiler bug:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Object
{
private:
    Object( Object const& );
    Object( Object&& );
public:
    void doSomething() const {}
    Object( int ) {}
    Object( int, int, int ) {}
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 0, p3 = 0;
    bool condition = argc == 2;

    auto const doSomething1 = [=]() { Object o( p1 ); o.doSomething(); };
    auto const doSomething2 = [=]() { Object o( p1, p2, p3 ); o.doSomething(); };

    if( condition ) { doSomething1(); } else { doSomething2(); }
}
```

Another answer maintains that `new` (read: a dynamic allocation) is your only option.

That's wrong.

Comment: Most of the compilers used in actual production will not accept your solution.  You need C++11 (still not yet widespread) for rvalue references and lambda functions.  But the basic idea is probably valid: move all of the code using the object into a function taking the object by reference, and then have two different variables in the function which calls it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: thanks, i suspected as much… and yes, the basic idea is also applicable in C++03, where it corresponds to either the workaround shown last, or the application of a function that yields a reference to a temporary in order to use the more straightforward original construction. i do not understand why the answer where you have to choose between an unreasonable requirement (default-constructable) + possible side effect, or inefficiency of dynamic allocation + dependency on big library, has been selected as “the solution” – it’s about the worst possible answer IMHO – but such is SO.

Comment: I certainly agree with you about the worst possible answer being the one selected as "the solution".  But as you say, such is SO.

Comment: @JamesKanze, well it's my choice ;-) But (as I commented when I accepted it) I felt it the 'best' answer because I learnt most from it: use of boost::in_place with boost::optional. The "terrible hack" is exactly that, and I wouldn't consider it. C++11 isn't an option, so this answer isn't - yet- *useful* for me, and the proliferation of little 'dosomething' functions in C++03 is not what I'd consider a 'clean' approach.

Answer (score 1):

There's really nothing wrong with your solution, although as
others have already mentionned, it would be more readably if you
used the conditional operator rather than if's.  But you should
consider the possibility of refactoring.  If you factor out all
of the code which uses the object into a separate function
(taking the object by reference), then something like:

```
if ( condition ) {
    Object a( p1 );
    doWhatever( a );
} else {
    Object a( p2, p3, p4 );
    doWhatever( a );
}
```

might be preferable (or not—I don't think that there's any
"right" answer with regards to choosing between these two).

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is OK.

You just may want to consider the *conditional operator* `? :`

```
boost::scoped_ptr<Object> a( condition ? new Object(p1) : new Object(p2,p3,p4) );
a->doSomething();
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well done for the stupid comment. I think readability (or lack of) is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Why turn to insults? Please don't do that.

Comment: really, who are those people upvoting comments about who's best at insulting or who's done it. pretty silly. anyway, re the answer, a dynamic allocation is a pretty high cost in C++, not to be incurred lightly, and especially not when easy alternatives exist, so i wouldn't do this

Comment: The conditional operator certainly improves the readability here, but it doesn't address his specific problem, since it also requires support for copy.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a quick trick to make this work, without manually constructing objects.  Instead, I created a `Deferred<T>` template that represents an object in automatic storage whose construction is deferred (and possibly never occurs).

The `buff` in `Deferred` should be replaced with a `union`, because that will handle alignment issues (assuming you have C++11 features to support that).  Asserts that `constructed` is true when you call `get()` is probably a good idea.

Once you have constructed your object, you can implicitly cast your `Deferred<T>` to a `T&`, then use that `T&` as an alias to the deferred-constructed `T`.

In theory, you could do away with the `constructed` `bool` if you could prove that it would always be constructed, but I'd advise against it.  Other than that, this should be nearly as efficient as you can pull it off.  And with the C++11 `union` case, it might even be standards compliant.

Oh yes, and it should be enhanced with perfect forwarding.

```
#include <utility>

// does not handle alignment issues:
template<typename T>
struct Deferred {
   Deferred():constructed(false) {}
  operator T&() { return get(); }
  T& get() { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&buff[0]); }
  template<typename... Args>
  T& construct( Args... args ) {
    new(&buff[0]) T(args...);
    constructed = true;
    return get();
  }
  ~Deferred() {
    if (constructed) {
      get().~T();
    }
  }
private:
  bool constructed;
  char buff[sizeof(T)];
};

#include <iostream>

struct Object {
  bool is_int;
  Object( int x ):is_int(true) {}
  Object( double d ):is_int(false) {}
  ~Object() {
    std::cout << "~Object("<<is_int<<") destroyed\n";
  }
};

enum which_test {
  as_int,
  as_double,
  do_not,
};
void test(which_test v) {
  std::cout << v << "\n";
  Deferred<Object> o;
  if(v==as_int) {
    o.construct( 7 );
  } else if (v==as_double) {
    o.construct( 7.0 );
  } else {
  }
}

int main() {
  test(as_int);
  test(as_double);
  test(do_not);
}
```